# Matlab `localfunctions` function is undefined

Tags: matlab

I have tried following the advice [from the docs](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/localfunctions.html)  for using the `localfunctions` function.  When I execute the script in the MATLAB command window it gives the following error:

```
>> athing()
Undefined function or variable 'localfunctions'.

Error in athing (line 2)
    fs = localfunctions;
```

In the file `thing.m` I have written:

```
function fs = athing()
    fs = localfunctions;
end

function babo()
end

function hidden()
end
```

I'm not sure what else I can try to debug this. I am using MATLAB: 8.0.0.783 (R2012b).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`localfunctions`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/localfunctions.html) was only introduced in R2013b. You will need to update your version of MATLAB to R2013b or newer to be able to use it.

---

At the bottom of all function reference documentation on the Mathworks website is a comment stating the version it was introduced.

[image]

Comment: That's great.  Thanks so much.